# Present a UIViewController on top of UILocalizedIndexedCollation

Tags: ios, uitableview

IS it possible to add a UIViewController on top of a UITableView whilst hiding the UILocalizedIndexedCollation. I have added a UIViewController as a subview, but the UILocalizedIndexedCollation still shows up on top of the UIViewController. Here is a screenshot of what is happening.

[image: Notice the UILocalizedIndexedCollation on top of the view]

This is the code I use to show the UIViewController view.

```
[self willMoveToParentViewController:parentViewController];
[parentViewController.view addSubview:self.view];
[parentViewController addChildViewController:self];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A table view does not show a `UILocalizedIndexedCollation`. Your implementation of the table view data source methods might make use of a `UILocalizedIndexedCollation` to provide the data for the "index list" that appears down the right side of the table view.

If you wish to hide the index list, then you have two choices:

1) Return `nil` from the `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:` data source method and reload the table view. Return the proper list and reload the table again to show the index list.

2) Set the table view's `sectionIndexMinimumDisplayRowCount` property to `NSIntegerMax`. Set it back to 0 to show it again.